# Does it make sense to use TFS purely as a project management tool?

Tags: tfs, project-management, agile, project, process

Does it make sense to use the project management features of Team Foundation Server without using the Source Control and Automatic Build features? We're doing agile in an non-.net environment and would use TFS to manage the project but keep using the currently used source control and build software.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of TFS' primary strengths is that the work item tracking and source control are so closely linked.  Another of its primary strengths is the integration into the Visual Studio IDE.  It sounds like you wouldn't be using either of those features, so that starts to drive you away from using TFS as a solution.

Another factor that is an unknown here is how much you would need to pay for TFS licensing.  If you already have that covered under existing MSDN licenses, then it probably isn't a factor.

That being said, the agile process template in TFS 2010 is a very nice agile-in-a-box solution, giving you the work items and management reports that you need to work in an agile environment.  Additionally, you can modify the process template as needed to meet your particular flavor of agile.

Comment: We don't have MSDN licenses. Would it then make sense to use Sharepoint (cheaper) instead of TFS in my situation?

Comment: Depends on what you're going to use SharePoint for -- out of the box, you won't get any real project management tools from SharePoint.  What kind of stuff are you looking for from a project management standpoint?  Workplans, burn-down charts, etc?

Comment: If you need Agile planning and a Task Board with TFS Web Access, take a look at Urban Turtle - http://urbanturtle.com. According to Microsoft, this is the premier Scrum tooling for TFS.

Discloser: I work with the Urban Turtle team. So do not take my words. Instead, read what Microsoft blogs said about Urban Turtle. http://blogs.msdn.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=urban%20turtle&sections=3652.